# Attributing the value of a cell based on another corresponding cell

Tags: excel, vba

I many files of the sort: Sheet1 and Sheet2.

[image]

*Sheet1*

[image]

*Sheet2*

Is it possible that, when a user inputs a value in let's say B2 in Sheet2, that that value is automatically copied to B5 in Sheet1? So the user would type something, press enter, and B5 would have a new value.

I can do this when referencing a fixed range of cells (`Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B14").Value = Worksheets(2).Range("B1:B14").Value`), but in this case the range in Sheet1 is different than the range in Sheet2. Excel would have to find the corresponding cell first. How can I do that? I'm sure this is possible with without it, but preferably I'd use VBA.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Excel formulas

put in cell B1 of Sheet1:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B;MATCH(A1;Sheet2!A:A;0))
```

drag it down to all other Sheet1 column B cells

and you're done

---

If you are for a VBA solution, then place the following code in the Sheet2 code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case True
        Case Target.Column <> 2
        
        Case Intersect(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Range(Range("A1"), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))) Is Nothing
        
        Case Else
        
            On Error GoTo SafeExit
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Sheet2
                Dim f As Range
                    Set f = .Range(.Range("A1"), Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=Target.Offset(, -1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                    
                    If f Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "No match of '" & Target.Value & "' in '" & Sheet1.Name & "'"
                    Else
                        f.Offset(, 1).Value = Target.Value
                    End If                
            End With
    
    End Select

SafeExit:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for taking the time to help me! I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I can't seem to get the code to run... Excel simply won't find the macro.

Comment: You have to put the code in the Sheet2 worksheet code pane

Comment: To access that code pane, simply right-click on the tab name and choose “View code”

Comment: I feel quite incompetent right now... The formula works perfectly, thank you - I tried everything with the VBA code but I just can't get it to work. I did insert it in the code pane of Sheet2, and I don't get any errors, but for some reason it's not doing anything. First I'm supposed to insert the data in Sheet2, *then* I run the code, right?